# Improving the performance of an autoencoder network

Tags: performance, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, optuna

For a couple of days, I am working to improve the performance of my autoencoder network, from changing the network architecture to manually tuning some parameters and lately using [optuna](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to optimize hpyerparameters. All to no significant improvement in network performance.

May I know if there're a couple of suggestions you can make to improve this model?

Code:

```
def objective(trial):
    """Object function to optimize parameters"""
    #clear session
    keras.backend.clear_session()

    encoding_dim = 32
    input_shape  = x_train_sub.shape[1:]  #(1, 200, 4) input shape
    autoencoder  = Sequential()
    activ='relu'

    autoencoder.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(800, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dropout(trial.suggest_uniform('dropout_1', 0.0, 0.5)))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(600, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dropout(trial.suggest_uniform('dropout_2', 0.0, 0.5)))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(400, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dropout(trial.suggest_uniform('dropout_3', 0.0, 0.5)))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation=activ)) 
    autoencoder.add(Dense(80,  activation=activ)) 
    autoencoder.add(Dense(encoding_dim, activation=activ))   

    #decoder
    autoencoder.add(Dense(80, activation=activ))  
    autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation=activ)) 
    autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(400, activation=activ))        
    autoencoder.add(Dense(600, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(800, activation=activ))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(np.prod(input_shape), activation=activ)) 
    autoencoder.add(Reshape(input_shape))

    optimizer = Adam(lr=trial.suggest_loguniform("learning_rate", 1e-5, 1e-1)) 
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    hist = autoencoder.fit(x_train_sub, x_train_sub, epochs=200, verbose = 0,
        batch_size = trial.suggest_categorical('batch_size', [64, 128]), shuffle=True)
    min_mse = np.min(hist.history['mean_squared_error'])#min mean_squared_error

    return min_mse
```

Create an optuna study:

```
study = optuna.create_study(study_name='ae_study', direction='minimize')
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=150)
```

Then train fit the model with `study parameters like so:

```
output = study.best_params
dropout_list = [] #loop to form dropouts list from study best parameters

def createModel():
        encoding_dim = 32
        input_shape  = x_train.shape[1:]  #(1, 100, 4) 
        autoencoder  = Sequential()
        activ='relu'

        # encoder
        autoencoder.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(800, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dropout(dropout_list[0]))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(600, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dropout(dropout_list[1]))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(400, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dropout(dropout_list[2]))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation=activ)) 
        autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation=activ)) 
        autoencoder.add(Dense(80,  activation=activ)) 
        autoencoder.add(Dense(encoding_dim, activation=activ))   
        
        #decoder
        autoencoder.add(Dense(80, activation=activ))  
        autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation=activ)) 
        autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(400, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(600, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(800, activation=activ))
        autoencoder.add(Dense(np.prod(input_shape), activation=activ)) 
        autoencoder.add(Reshape(input_shape))

        optimizer = Adam(lr=output['learning_rate']) 
        autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae', 
                            metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
        autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=250, batch_size=output['batch_size'], 
            shuffle=True) 

        return autoencoder
```

Unfortunately, no significant improvement to my model performance despite all these efforts. What do you suggest I should do further?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the final metric of this auto-encoder.

But each trial needs to return some metric on a validation set rather than on a training set to avoid over-fitting.

In addition, in my opinion, the network architecture looks too large regarding the input's shape.

Comment: thank you for this, the objective function seeks to minimize the reconstruction error `mean square error`.